# Parallel calls to google.appengine.api.channel.send_message

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

I am using `send_message(client_id, message)` in `google.appengine.api.channel` to fan out messages. The most common use case is two users. A typical trace looks like the following:

[image: Trace]

The two calls to `send_message` are independent. Can I perform them in parallel to save latency?

Answer (score 1):

Well there's no async api available, so you might need to implement a custom solution.

Have you already tried with native [threading](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html)? It could work in theory, but because of the GIL, the xmpp api must block by I/O, which I'm not sure it does.

A custom implementation will invariably come with some overhead, so it might not be the best idea for your simple case, unless it breaks the experience for the >2 user cases.

There is, however, another problem that might make it worth your while: what happens if the instance crashes and only got to send the first message? The api isn't transactional, so you should have some kind of safeguard. Maybe a simple recovery mode will suffice, given how infrequently this will happen, but I'm willing to bet a transactional message channel sounds more appealing, right?

Two ways you could go about it, off the top of my head:

- Push a [task](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/) for every message, they're transactional and guaranteed to run, and will execute in parallel with a fairly identical run time. It'll increase the time it takes for the first message to go out but will keep it consistent between all of them.
- Use a service built for this exact use case, like [firebase](https://www.firebase.com/) (though it might even be too powerful lol), in my experience the channel api is not very consistent and the performance is underwhelming for gaming, so this might make your system even better.

Comment: I suppose I should try threading. I am worried that the latency of the task queue will be greater than the saved latency in the request handler. Instance crashes happens rarely enough to not be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

***Fixed that for you***

I just posted a patch on [googleappengine issue 9157](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9157#c3), adding:

- `channel.send_message_async` for asynchronously sending a message to a recipient.
- `channel.send_message_multi_async` for asynchronously **broadcasting** a single message to multiple recipients.
- Some helper methods to make those possible.

Until the patch is pushed into the SDK, you'll need to include the `channel_async.py` file (that's attached on [that thread](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9157#c3)).

**Usage**

```
import channel_async as channel

# this is synchronous D:
channel.send_message(<client-id>, <message>)

# this is asynchronous :D
channel.send_message_async(<client-id>, <message>)

# this is good for broadcasting a single message to multiple recipients
channel.send_message_multi_async([<client-id>, <client-id>], <message>)
# or
channel.send_message_multi_async(<list-of-client-ids>, <message>)
```

**Benefits**

Speed comparison on production:

- Synchronous model: **2 - 80 ms** per recipient (and *blocking* -.-)
- Asynchronous model: **0.15 - 0.25 ms** per recipient